# RTL bulma css navbar

Tags: css, right-to-left, bulma

I am trying to add the option for RTL users in my site. I am using bulma (V 0.5.2), most of it (the rtl) is working out of the box with a simple `"style=direction:rtl"` on the body tag. However, the navbar is acting funny. How can I make it work correctly with RTL?

This is what it looks like on desktop with rtl:

[image: This is what it looks like on desktop with rtl]

And on mobile it's like this:

[image: And on mobile it's like this]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, i have solved it by digging a bit in the code and understanding what should be changed in oreder for it to work properly as RTL navbar.

We have three main sections in the navbar, and i recommend making a class for it in you app.css or whatever name you have for your css called `rtl-navbar` and apply it on `navbar-burger`, `navbar-end`. on top of this, you should apply `direction:rtl` on the main navbar container.

```
.navbar-rtl{
   margin-right: auto;
   margin-left: 0;
}
```